# Dynamically choosing a schema name in a view

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a view for multiple tables with the same structure but in different schemas:

```
create table a.persons (
    name text primary key
);
create table b.persons (
    name text primary key
);
create view dynamic_persons as select * from SCHEMA.persons;
```

I want to be a able to get `SCHMEA` dynamically from a function or jwt attribute (`current_setting('jwt.claims.schema')` for example).
Is it possible to do?

Answer (score 0):

you are supposed to `set schema` or `set search_path to` or `select set_config` to change he schema, but the view definition is saved, thus to run it dynamically you will have to recreate view on each run, which does not make sense.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a table function for that. Create a function, that takes an argument and depending on that argument either queries `a.persons` or `b.persons`.

Example:

```
CREATE TYPE schema_switch AS ENUM ('a', 'b');

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION dynamic_view (_schema schema_switch)
RETURNS TABLE (name text)
AS
$$
DECLARE
  x INT;
BEGIN
  CASE 
    WHEN _schema ='a'
      THEN RETURN QUERY SELECT persons.name
                               FROM a.persons;
    WHEN _schema ='b'
      THEN RETURN QUERY SELECT persons.name
                               FROM b.persons;
  END CASE;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Called like `dynamic_view('a')` would return the records from `a.persons`, `dynamic_view('b')` those from `b.persons`.

In the example I created a new enum type here only allowing `'a'` or `'b'` for input. That makes it less error prone. But you could of course also do it with a `varchar` and [`RAISE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-errors-and-messages.html) an error, if an invalid value was passed. You could also use dynamic SQL to allow passing an arbitrary schema name using [`RETURN QUERY EXECUTE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-RETURNING). But be sure to check the input for sanity then.Like look up `pg_catalog.pg_namespace` if such a schema exists.

Maybe there is also a possibility doing it with [rules](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/rules.html) instead of a function.